How to setup NTP
Can someone guide me how to set up NTP .
I have tried installing update and stop and restart the server but still the issue permits the same .
Can someone guide me on this please .
Thank you

Why do you need NTP? Ubuntu ships with systemd-timesyncd, is this not working out for you? You should probably specify exactly what isn't working out for you, and what you want to achieve.

If you need NTP for a server you should look into chronyd or such, the actual NTP server is considered "insecure' in most setups

Thanks for the response @ArturMeinild
Here wen we setup the ntp it is showing the ntp service is inactive , even after upgrade the packages  we have retstarted the server , stilll it is the same issue .
the error say like below :
NTP service : n/a
now we have to make it active , kindly assist .

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I just added this comment in server
sudo apt install chrony -y
the status came back to active
Now i wanted to know why it was removed earlier and what was reason .
Was it because of the upgradation ??

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
